# How to automate configuration of /home which files are more than 10 day's

Tags: scripts

i want to move the files older than 10 day's to backup path
when i have used based on the below commands it was working fine for me when i ran individual each command

```
find /home/abc/def/xyz-sw-n2/log/ -type f -name *.txt -mtime +10 -print

find /home/abc/def/xyz-sw-n2/accesslog/ -type f -name *.csv -mtime +10 -print

find /home/abc/def/eguard/ -type f -name *.csv -mtime +10 -print

find /home/abc/def/xxxv6/logs/ -type f -name *.csv -mtime +10 -print

find /home/abc/def/yyy/request/log/ -type f -name *.log -mtime +10 -print

find /home/abc/def/zzz-core/logs -type f -name *.log -mtime +10 -print
```

when i ran this below command  there is a problem that if any configuration file or important file which is with *.csv or *.log or *.txt will get moved

or

```
find . -type f \( -name *.csv -o -name *.txt -o -name *.log \) -mtime +10 -print
```

in your system there is no particular format naming convention for the log's *.csv or *.log or *.txt

how to make it automate

Answer (score 4):

Put the `name` specifiers between double quotes:

```
find . -type f \( -name "*.csv" -o -name "*.txt" -o -name "*.log" \) -mtime +10 -print
```

works on my system.

Comment: If the ```-name``` argument in ```find``` command contains wildcards, it should **always** be written in quotes. Even the ```man``` page for the ```find``` command says that.

Comment: Hi Jos,

Thanks for the update but my concern is

if i ran the below command it will move the main configuration file.

find . -type f \( -name "*.csv" -o -name "*.txt" -o -name "*.log" \) -mtime +10 -print 

for example:

find /home/abc/def/xyz-sw-n2/log/ -type f -name *.txt -mtime +10 -print

find /home/abc/def/xyz-sw-n2/alerts/config/email/1234/ -type f -name *.txt -mtime +10 -print (Main Config File)

Comment: @JagadishKumar I don't understand your comment. In your question, you never mention a main config file, and none of the commands moves anything.

Comment: @jos i want to move the log's